# In PostgreSQL, what to do after VALIDATE CONSTRAINT succeeds on a constraint marked with NO VALID?

Tags: postgresql, constraint

So, I get the rough gist of changing constraints on existing columns with PostgreSQL:

- Use `NO VALID` to ensure the new constraint does not lock the table.
- Migrate the old data at your leisure.
- Run `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT` at some point to check if the column is consistent.

My question is then, do you ever remove `NO VALID`? If the point is to avoid locking the table with `ADD CONSTRAINT`, it seems like no? After all, if you drop `NO VALID` after the success of `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT`, won't you still lock the table?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  VALIDATE automatically removes the NOT VALID, and there is no other way of doing so.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense - thank you!

Comment: For reference, the procedure in use here is described in the [Notes section in the `ALTER TABLE` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-NOTES), in the paragraph starting with "Scanning a large table". `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT` takes a `SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE` lock which is weaker than the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock that `ALTER TABLE` normally takes, allowing concurrent access.

Answer (score 1):

As @jjanes said, this question makes no sense, as VALIDATE removes NOT VALID. I did not realize that, but now I do!